# How to do a three group boxplot in R with 3 columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm calculating some stats for 3 groups - all, male, and female. I've stored them in a data frame called stats_df that has each group as a column header with the stats as the row data. I need to do a `boxplot` (my most current attempt is included in the code) that has all 3 groups represented as boxes, but I can't seem to figure it out and no online tutorials are helping. Data:

[image]

Code:

```
all_stats <- c(all_mean, all_median, all_mode, all_25, all_50, all_75)
female_stats <- c(female_mean, female_median, female_mode, female_25, female_50, female_75)
male_stats <- c(male_mean, male_median, male_mode, male_25, male_50, male_75)

stats_df <- data.frame(all_stats, female_stats, male_stats)

boxplot(all_stats ~ male_stats,
        data=stats_df, 
        main="Stats Boxplot",
        xlab="Group", 
        ylab="Number")
```

Comment: Please provide sample data in code form rather than with a screenshot - we can't import a screenshot into R, so as things stand, you're asking us to to first copy your data value by value into R... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
stats_df <- data.frame(all_stats = c(35.19, 32, 29, 26, 32, 50),
                       female_stats = c(36.23, 32, 32, 24, 32, 52),
                       male_stats = c(33.5, 32, 29, 28.5, 32, 39.5))

library(tidyverse)
stats_df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "all_stats", y = all_stats)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "female_stats", y = female_stats)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = "male_stats", y = male_stats)) +
  xlab("Group") +
  ylab("Number") +
  ggtitle("Stats Boxplot")
```

Output:

[image]